# ViewPager.setAdapter() throwing NullPointException; viewPager and pagerAdapter don't seem null?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-viewpager

So I am messing around with using `ViewPager` in tandem with `Navigation Drawer`. I have the `Navigation Drawer` working.

However, attempting to call `viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter)` is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

I am checking both `viewPager` and `pagerAdapter` for null, but here is what happens when I attempt to `Log` calls to their respective `toString()` methods:

```
03-11 12:31:54.156: D/My Debug Bitches(2893): android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{b1e75710 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090000 app:id/pager}
03-11 12:31:54.156: D/MyDebugBitches(2893): com.sweidenkopf.discretesuite.DataSetViewActivity$DataSetViewPagerAdapter@b1e7b4c8
```

Notice how the `viewPager` `toString()` returns some weird `android.support.v4`information? I think that may have something to do with this issue.

Here is the initialization of my `viewPager` and `pagerAdapter`. I marked the line that is causing the exception

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle args) {
    super.onCreate(args);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_set_view);
    super.onCreateDrawer();
    //initialize the pager adapter, giving it access to the fragment manager
    pagerAdapter = new DataSetViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //initialize the view pager!
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Log.d("My Debug Bitches", viewPager.toString());
    Log.d("MyDebugBitches", pagerAdapter.toString());
    //here we give the pager its adapter
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);//<-- this is causing exception
}
```

Here is the layout xml `R.layout.activity_data_set_view` that is being used by this activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the logcat:

```
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893): Process: com.sweidenkopf.discretesuite, PID: 2893
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893): java.lang.NullPointerException  
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:389)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-11 12:31:54.476: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at       dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit:
I changed my `null` checking to this:

```
 //initialize the view pager!
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if(viewPager == null){
        Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "viewPager is null");
    }
    if(pagerAdapter == null){
        Log.d("MyDebugBitches", "pagerAdapter is null");
    }
```

Neither of the `Log` calls were triggered, which makes me think neither the `viewPager` nor the `pagerAdapter` are `null`

and here is my pager adapter:

```
private class DataSetViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public DataSetViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * This method must return the number of tabs, which is the length of the 
     * view_pager_tabs string array (it contains the names of all of the tabs)
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.view_pager_tabs).length;
    }

    /**
     * returns the element with in the view_pager_tabs array that corresponds with
     * the given position
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.view_pager_tabs)[position];
    }



}
```

Comment: why `super.getSupportFragmentManager()`? Can you post the adapter?

Comment: A few things. Where are you checking for NULL on either of viewPager or pagerAdapter? I don't see it in your posted code.  Second, the reason you see the 'android.support.v4' information in your toString() method is because that is how the item is declared in the xml file:  `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android`.  My first suspicion is that `findViewById(R.id.pager)` is failing and therefore you are casting a NULL value to your viewPager.  Please re-post code that shows you are checking for NULL.

Comment: @Blackbelt that was a last-ditch attempt to get this to work ;) it didn't work before hand either.

Comment: @blh83 I wasn't explicitly checking for NULL; rather, I was logging the toString() call on viewPager. Normally, this call will cause the program to crash if the caller is NULL. I will do a better NULL check though hold on

Comment: @blh83 see my edit. INeither of the `if-statements` were triggered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

your problem is here. Your `getItem` can't return null. Internally the `ViewPager` creates some transaction for the fragment you return in `getItem`, and you can't add a null fragment to a transaction

Comment: wow I didn't think that method was actually being called. Thanks!! I just set the method up to temporarily return an empty fragment for now